# How to install Dart SDK for Fedora 37?

Tags: dart, installation, sdk, fedora, apt-get

I cannot install dart sdk on fedora.

I tried through apt-get (official website), but it doesnt work.
Also some troubles to do this through python3

Comment: Have you tried [installing the Dart SDK from a ZIP file](https://dart.dev/get-dart/archive#stable-channel)?

Answer (score 0):

[Update] Completed the two steps below, and got flutter/dart up and running on Android Studio Electric Eel.
I'm about to do this myself this afternoon. From the flutter documentation it looks like dart is packaged up with flutter. have you been able to use snap to install flutter?

If not -

1. [install snap package manager](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/install-snapd-on-fedora-linux-system-dnf-command/)
2. [Then install flutter using snap](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux#install-flutter-using-snapd)

Hope this helps.
-TMT

[2023 Flutter documentation explaining dart bundling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAlKd.png)